# Is there a way to create and use a random email address for a POST request in CYpress

Tags: cypress

I'm currently using fixtures for POST requests

```
cy.fixture('CreateCredentials').then(list1 => {
      cy.request('POST', '/api/v1/Credentials', list1)
    })
```

I want to create and save a random email in my **.json** file *CreateCredentials* and then also re use it in the **spec.js** file: `cy.get('[data-cy=email]').type('use random email here')`

```
 {
    "Username": "Create and Save random email here",
    "password": "pass123" 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of aliasing: [`.as()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Using-an-alias-to-access-a-fixture).

Example with your scenario:

```
cy.fixture('CreateCredentials').as('jsonData')

cy.request('POST', '/api/v1/Credentials', this.jsonData)

cy.get('[data-cy=email]').type(this.jsonData.Username)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.

When i try the .as method i get a TypeError
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'jsonData' of undefined`

Comment: @AmandeepGhag when using `as("aliasname")` the object is stored to the `this` context.- You thzen can access it with `this.aliasname`. But this works only if you use no phat arrow syntax in your `it()/test()` calls.

Comment: ah that makes sense, Thank you both